# How to make animation in MATLAB which the curve is moving, not axes is moving?

Tags: matlab, animation, curve

I want to plot y=omega*x^2, which omega is -3 into 3 with step size 0.25, x from -4 into 4 with step size 0.001. But this code give me the curve is cannot moving and axes is moving. I want the curve is moving, like this.

[image]

```
x=-4:0.001:4;
for omega=-3:0.25:3
    for i=1:length(x)
        y(i)=omega*x(i)^2;
    end
    plot(x,y);
    pause(0.1);
end
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As another answer has indicated, you need to set the axis limits.

(Also note that there is no reason to calculate `y` using a loop.)

But instead of using `plot` every time through the loop it's more efficient to create the line only once, and then replace the `x` and `y` data of the line each time through the loop.

```
x=-4:0.001:4;
all_omega=-3:0.25:3;
for idx = 1:numel(all_omega)
    omega = all_omega(idx);
    y=omega*(x.^2);
    if idx == 1
        % create line
        hl = plot(x,y);
        axis([-4,4,-40,40]);
        box on
        grid on
    else
        % replace line data
        set(hl,'XData',x,'YData',y);
    end
    title(sprintf('\\Omega = %.2f',omega)); 
    pause(0.1); 
end
```

Or you might want to use `animatedline`,

```
x=-4:0.001:4;
all_omega=-3:0.25:3;
for idx = 1:numel(all_omega)
    omega = all_omega(idx);
    y=omega*(x.^2);
    if idx == 1
        % create animated line
        am = animatedline(x,y);
        axis([-4,4,-40,40]);
        box on
        grid on
    else
        % replace the line
        clearpoints(am)
        addpoints(am,x,y);
    end
    title(sprintf('\\Omega = %.2f',omega));
    pause(0.1);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick method is setting the x- and y-axes limits in the loop after each plot, using the axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]) command. This method isn't foolproof, in the case that the script gets help up after plotting but before setting the axes limits, but in most cases it should work.

```
figure(1)
x=-4:0.001:4;
for omega=-3:0.25:3
    for i=1:length(x)
        y(i)=omega*x(i)^2;
    end
    plot(x,y);
    axis([-4 4 -50 50])
    pause(0.1);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as @phil-goddard's answer, but makes more efficient use of handles to the animated YData and title string.

```
x = -4 : 0.001 : 4;
y = zeros(1, numel(x));
omega_range = -3 : 0.25 : 3;

% Create line and title, and obtain handles to them.
h_plot = plot(x, y);
axis([-4, 4, -40, 40]);
box on;
grid on;
h_title = title(sprintf('\\omega = %.2f', 0));

for idx = 1:numel(omega_range)
    omega = omega_range(idx);
    y = omega * (x.^2);

    % Replace y data.
    h_plot.YData = y;

    % Replace title string.
    h_title.String = sprintf('\\omega = %.2f', omega);
    pause(0.1);
end
```